# Is there a synchronization conflict in this given example?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

In my code, I use a synchronized block on the resource `set` inside another synchronized block on the same resource. This did not cause me any problems so far, but I'm curious: what are the consequences if any? Will these synchronized blocks conflict with each other?

```
Set<myClass> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<myClass>());

synchronized(set) {
    set.add(new myClass());
    ...
    writeSetContentsToFile();
}

public synchronized void writeSetContentsToFile() {
    synchronized(set) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The set is accessed and changed continously by other threads. I synchronized `writeSetContentsToFile()`, so there won't be any conflicts at the file resource, and again, there is a synchronized block inside `writeSetContentsToFile()`, to make sure no changes are made to the set while iterating over it.

Comment: Syncrhonized blocks are reentrant, so on the same thread, it should not cause any problem.

Comment: @Daniel it may be that doing `synchronized` twice is redundant in `writeSetContentsToFile()`, unless `set` isn't a member of type owning  the method. And, usually, you should take the most fine-grained lock  you have, which here seems to be `set`, to improve throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This did not cause me any problems so far, but I'm curious: what are the consequences if any?

In some ways you answered your own question, it works but its confusing. Its best to simplify the code if you can. You would need to look at the rest of the code to determine whether this is possible.

Comment: It's my understanding that Java synchronization is thread-specific, so that won't ever be a problem. What exactly is confusing about the code?

Comment: You have four different places where synchronisation occurs when the minimum is one. I suspect not all of them are needed. If you use a concurrent collection you might be able to avoid them all.

Comment: The set is accessed and changed continously by other threads. I synchronized `writeSetContentsToFile()`, so there won't be any conflicts at the file resource, and again, there is a synchronized block inside `writeSetContentsToFile()`, to make sure no changes are made to the set while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two locks here, the one on `this`, and the one on `set`. If two threads lock them in different orders, BANG. Deadlock. You haven't shown all your code, so this might not be possible, but what about when someone changes the class to add a new method?

As Peter Lawrey says, you should try to simplify this code.

Answer (score 1):

If your operation expressed in

```
synchronized(set) {
    set.add(new myClass());
    ...
    writeSetContentsToFile();
}
```

is atomic, encapsulate it in separate class, say, `ThreadSafeFileStorableSet` under dedicated method, say, `synchronized writeContentsToFile()`.

For example:

```
class ThreadSafeFileStorableSet {
    private final Set set;

    ThreadSafeFileStorableSet(Set set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    synchronized void writeSetContentsToFile() {
        // 
    }

    synchronized void addElements(Object[] elems) {
        // 
    }

    private void doWrite() {
        // use instance set
    }
}
```

Make all other non-private methods of `ThreadSafeFileStorableSet` class `synchronized` too, so all operations will be atomic to each other. Then you won't need `synchronized (set)` snippets inside this class.

This will simplify your code, but may make concurrency level worse. But I don't have enough information to advise on how much worse it could become from reading your code.